# Most lightweight Ubuntu-based linux distro 2021

Tags: linux, ubuntu, distributions, lightweight

I'm a Ubuntu user, but my computer is getting older so I cannot use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm used to use Lubuntu 18.04 LTS and that works, but the support time runs out this year.

So I need to replease current linux OS for a better one. The current linux OS I'm using is AntiX Linux. It's super fast, but It's quite weird because everything is old here. Old software and AntiX is based on Debian 10.

I don't have so much problem with AntiX Linux, except when I try to install software. These softwares are so old, that I dosen't support some files or functions e.g GNU Octave.

So I need a Linux system that are based on Ubuntu, but take less memory than Lubuntu 18.04 LTS or as much as 18.04 LTS. The support time is important too.

What is the best lightweight Ubuntu based linux distro 2021 that follow this requriments:

- No more RAM usage than 256 Mb
- Pentium 4 or less
- Support time to 2025 or more
- Based on Ubuntu
- 64-bit

Comment: You'll probably need a lightweight window manager like openbox or i3. https://www.bunsenlabs.org/ comes to mind, however it is based on Debian instead of Ubuntu. What if you just upgrade to Lubuntu 20.04 (when it becomes available), and then replace LXDE with openbox as your window manager?

Comment: I doubt you can install new software with those specifications. Ubuntu's tend to follow the newest releases, which at this moment are the only ones with LTS time.

Comment: What do you think about Puppy Linux 9.5?

Comment: I second @thiagowfx. I first had Lubuntu 20.10, I stripped everything unnecessary and use openbox with picom, it uses only 225 MB RAM on idle. I can't comment about the processor though. I have an i3-4010U

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I didn't know it was based on Ubuntu, but [Minimum System Requirements: 64bit core2duo cpu & 2gb ram](https://distro.ibiblio.org/puppylinux/puppy-fossa/release-fossapup64-9.5.htm).

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Well, I have 4 GB ram. But I want not to use everything directly.

Comment: Are you sure you want it to be based on Ubuntu? Perhaps you are thinking of Debian? Ubuntu is based on Debian so anything that is based on Debian will probably work as you expect it so you don't need to restrict your options to Ubuntu-based.

Comment: I will try with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and install JWM manager.

Comment: @terdon The problem with debian based systems is that.....old software....

Comment: No, that is not true at all. That's up to you and what repositories you point to. Most of your requirements are up to you, really. You could also try with something based on Arch and just install what you need. Most of your RAM will be eaten by the GUI and your browsers anyway.

Comment: Finding the best, is a problem that is not even verifiable. Can you give a better success criteria.

Comment: I'll toss [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_Linux_distribution) into the mix. Something there may fit the bill, though you'll need to do your own research from there.

Comment: See the answer now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with JWM window manager, but I switched it to IceWM because JWM had problems with the short cuts at the start meny. IceWM works like a charm.

Then I upgrade 18.04 to 20.04 LTS and after that, I uninstalled Ubuntu Unity.
Now the desktop takes about 220 Mb in RAM in idle.

I tried first installed 20.04 LTS, but it did not have support for my computer directly. The screen was black. So upgrading 18.04 -> 20.04 and replaced Unity with IceMW and changed the IceMW theme to Win95, made my day.

It works for my old computer from 2008 - Dell Precision M6500.